# Create button to center map with all the active layers

Tags: leaflet

I have a map with different layers. The user can choose between them with a *L.control.layers*. Is it possible to add a button that would center the map with all the active layers?

Thanks for any tips,

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your layers to a FeatureGroup and then get the bounds. With that bounds you can center the map with `map.fitBounds(bounds)`:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

layer1.addTo(fg);
layer2.addTo(fg);
....

function centerMap(){
   map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds());
}
```

As button you can use a default html button:

```
<button onclick="centerMap()">Center Map</button>
```